# choose a constexpr based on a runtime value and use it inside a hot loop

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I need to traverse a `vector`, read each element, and map to the modulo division value. Modulo division is fast for divisors of power2. So, I need to choose between a `mod` and `mod_power2` during the runtime. Following is a rough outline. Please assume that I am using templates to visit the vector.

Bit manipulation tricks were taken from [https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html)

```cpp
static inline constexpr bool if_power2(int v) {
  return v && !(v & (v - 1));
}

static inline constexpr int mod_power2(int val, int num_partitions) {
  return val & (num_partitions - 1);
}

static inline constexpr int mod(int val, int num_partitions) {
  return val % num_partitions;
}

template<typename Func>
void visit(const std::vector<int> &data, Func &&func) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    func(i, data[i]);
  }
}

void run1(const std::vector<int> &v1, int num_partitions, std::vector<int> &v2) {
  if (if_power2(num_partitions)) {
    visit(v1,
          [&](size_t i, int v) {
            v2[i] = mod_power2(v, num_partitions);
          });
  } else {
    visit(v1,
          [&](size_t i, int v) {
            v2[i] = mod(v, num_partitions);
          });
  }
}

void run2(const std::vector<int> &v1, int num_partitions, std::vector<int> &v2) {
  const auto part = if_power2(num_partitions) ? mod_power2 : mod;

  visit(v1, [&](size_t i, int v) {
    v2[i] = part(v, num_partitions);
  });
}
```

My question is, `run1` vs `run2`. I prefer `run2` because it is easy to read and no code duplication. But when when I check both in godbolt (https://godbolt.org/z/3ov59rb5s), AFAIU, `run1` is inlined better than `run2`.

So, is there a better way to write a `run` function without compromising on the perf?

FOLLOW UP:

I ran a quickbench on this.
https://quick-bench.com/q/zO5YJtDMbnd10pk53SauOT6Bu0g

It looks like for clang, there's no difference. But for GCC (10.3) there's a 2x perf gain for `run1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Issue" with `cond ? mod_power2 : mod` is that it is a function pointer, which is *harder* to inline.

Different lambdas have no common type. Using type-erasure such as `std::function` has overhead, and devirtualization is even harder to optimize.

So, only option I see is to be able to write `run1` in a *"nicer"* way:

Factorize the creation of the lambda; you need to turn `mod`/`mod_power2` into functors (else we have same issue than `run2` [Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/x03_-HHAN6KebWtWrXmKXSx3Y9w)):

```
void run3(const std::vector<int> &v1, int num_partitions, std::vector<int> &v2) {
  auto make_lambda = [&](auto&& f){
    return [&](std::size_t i, int v){ v2[i] = f(v, num_partitions); };
  };
  if (if_power2(num_partitions)) {
    visit(v1, make_lambda(mod_power2));
  } else {
    visit(v1, make_lambda(mod));
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/WhJBI1a1_J7Z3D57bgxkkwqfBDI)

If you cannot change `mod`/`mod_power2` into functors, then create a functor instead of the lambda to got their address at compile time:

```
template <int (*f)(int val, int num_partitions)>
struct Functor
{
  std::vector<int> &v2;
  int num_partitions;

  void operator ()(size_t i, int v) const
  {
    v2[i] = f(v, num_partitions);
  }

};

void run4(const std::vector<int> &v1, int num_partitions, std::vector<int> &v2) {
  if (if_power2(num_partitions)) {
    visit(v1, Functor<mod_power2>{v2, num_partitions});
  } else {
    visit(v1, Functor<mod>{v2, num_partitions});
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/ETuSYC5Oqnb9jlXcYywNWuX9x8A)